# Linux/Firefox- snapping open tab from another machine

Tags: linux, firefox

Is there a way to snap the currently open tab(s) on Firefox (or any other browser) on Linux?

I have full user access to that machine...

Comment: What do you mean by "snap"?

Answer (score 2):

If by "snapping" you mean transferring one tab from one process on machine A, to another process on machine B, then no, you can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a strategy:

1. Get the X window id of the browser window containing the current tab that you want to snap. You can use [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) or [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) for this.
2. Use ImageMagick's import command to "snap" the currently open tab:

   $ import -windowid $window_id tabNNN.png
3. Use some scripting to ask the browser to go to the next/previous tab in the list of open tabs. You can use xdotool to simulate the key presses or do a remote connection to the browser (chrome allows you to do this).
4. Repeat from step 2.

Here's a one liner that captures all open windows in X:

```
$ for i in `xdotool search .`;do import -windowid $i $i.png;done
```

Good luck!

Comment: Sounds like a too time consuming procedure for now. Thanks for the effort...